# Tree based navigation, toggle only the clicked element Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this kind of vertical menu :-

```
Europe
 France
  Paris
 Germany
  Berlin

Asia
 India
  New Delhi
  Lucknow
 Bangladesh
  Dhaka
```

What I want to achieve is that if I click on Asia only the elements inside asia should open i.e. only the countries in Asia (not the cities right now) and when I click on the country only the cities of that country should open.

My Jquery looks like this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.country_name').hide();
     $('.city_name').hide();
     $('.continent_name').click(function(){

        $('.country_name').toggle(); 

        $('.city_name').hide();
     });

     $('.country_name').click(function(){

        $('.city_name').toggle();
     });
});
```

As you can see it toggles all the elements. How do I go about getting the desired result. I did the search on SO and tried few of the answers but it seems they don't work in my case.

**Update :-**

Here is the html code (it is in haml)

```
- @destinations.group_by(&:continent).each do |continent, ds_per_continent|
                %ul(class = "continent_name")
                    %li=link_to continent, "#"
                - ds_per_continent.group_by(&:country).each do |country, ds_per_country|
                    %ul(class = "country_name")
                        %li=link_to country, "#"
                    - ds_per_country.each do |destination|
                        %ul(class = "city_name")
                            %li=link_to destination.name, destination_path(destination)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("li").click(function(event) {
  $(this).children().toggle();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[A Live Example](http://jsbin.com/umuhin/4/edit#javascript,html,live)

I would also suggest you try to outsource your tree needs, I prefer [dynaTree](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `click` event handler, use the `$(this)` selector to refer to the clicked element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.country_name').hide();
     $('.city_name').hide();
     $('.continent_name').click(function(){

        $(this).find('.country_name').toggle();

        $('.city_name').hide();
     });

     $('.country_name').click(function(){

        $(this).find('.city_name').toggle();
     });
});
```

Comment: I assumed that your country elements are children of the continent elements. If that's not the case, you have to adjust the selectors. Without the html code it is hard to tell what's wrong.